Spring batch job using less than 1 cpu despite thread pool of size 20
I have the below step configured that is running super slow.  On our own servers it runs in less than 20 minutes but in the cloud it takes 10+ hours.  We have cpu request set to 4 and limit of 20 (this is in GCP).  Executor core pool size is set to 20.  Yet gcp monitoring says we are using less than 1 cpu the entirety of the step.  Any thoughts as to what is going on?
<batch:step id="mystep">
    <batch:tasklet task-executor="executor" throttle-limit="20" transaction-manager="dummyTransactionManager">
        <batch:chunk reader="myReader" processor="myProcessor"
            writer="myWriterr" skip-limit="1000000" commit-interval="50" retry-limit="0">
            <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                <batch:include class="myException"/>
            </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="myListener"/>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener>
            <bean class="myListener"/>
        </batch:listener>
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:step>


Try to remove the throttle-limit (which is deprecated) and increase the size of your task-executor.

what is your reasoning for these suggestions?  why increase executor size when less than 1 tcpu is being used as it is?  also, we are on spring batch 4.3.4

The reasoning is that the throttle limit is not behaving as expected, that's why it is deprecated. So you need to let the task executor handle that.
